# When processing multiple files, can output be redirected to a separate file for each input file?

Tags: command-line, io-redirection, wildcards

I execute something like this:

```
% command *bin > log.txt
```

`*b` expands to `a.bin`, `b.bin`, `c.bin`.

I would like stdout from each file to end up in a separate `log.txt` (or rather, a.txt, b.txt, c.txt). **How do I do this?**

When searching I have found a lot of questions about generating multiple log files from processing one file (e.g., `$ command a.bin > log1.txt log2.txt log3.txt`) but nothing that applies to my case (it surely exists but I drown in scenarios such as the one within the parenthesises).

Answer (score 1):

You have to process the files one-by-one if you want individual output files. You can't do it with redirection, because `STDOUT` (`STDERR` and `STDIN`, too) is set up by the parent process, before your command even starts, and your program never sees the `>log.txt`.

Do something like:

```
for i in "*.txt" ; do
    j="${i}.log"
    command "$i" >"$j"
done
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the command I running takes several minutes to launch and I have thousands of files to process.

Comment: Then your task is going to take several thousand minutes. 1000 minutes is 16 2/3 hours. Time to go outside and play, or optimize your process.